# Unique external IP per kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, rate-limiting

I need to scale my application so that it won't get banned for passing request rate-limit of a site it uses frequently (which allow up to X requests per minute per IP).
I meant to use kubernetes and split the requests between multiple workers, but I saw that all the pods get the same external IP.
so what can I do?

Comment: You can write a internal ingress and have it to do load balancing on the replicas.

Comment: @vancleff I read about that, and as I understand it, it wont affect the external IP

Comment: You should probably discuss with ( & pay ) the API provider, in order to increase your limit. Working around a third-party's protection mechanisms is not so nice !
... alternatively, could you do some caching in your application to reduce frequency of hits to the third party?

Answer (score 5):

I used kubernetes DaemonSet to attach pod to each node, and instead of scaling by changing deployment, I'm scaling by adding new nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you run in cloud you can create worker nodes with Public IP addresses. Then your pods will use node's public IP address. And then you can somehow distribute your pods across nodes using multiple replicas or DaemonSet.

Comment: Can multiple NAT gateways with public IP be helpful here ?

Comment: With NAT gateway you have to configure some custom routing per instance and overall I don't know if it's even possible. And it will cost you. On the other hand public IPs for instances are free of charge.

Comment: Use deployment instead of daemonset with node-affinity or node-antiaffinity with host as network.

Comment: Yes agreed NATs will cost. Shouldn't it be less than instance cost though ?

Comment: May be multiple NAT GWs is cheaper than multiple instances, but I have no idea how you gonna set up instance routing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

do not worry a bout getting one external IP because if you have 3 worker and one master like below

```
worker1   192.168.1.10
worker2   192.168.1.11
worker3   192.168.1.12
master    192.168.1.13
```

and forexample if you expose nginx on  30000 port the kubernetes open this port in every nod and you can access it by

```
curl 192.168.1.10:30000
curl 192.168.1.11:30000
curl 192.168.1.12:30000
curl 192.168.1.13:30000
```

and if you want to every worker have one pod you can use DaemonSet or you can use label to the node that you want

Answer (score 0):

This probably has less to do with your Kubernetes implementation and more to do with your network setup. It would depend on the source of the "exernal IP" you're referencing: is it given to you by your ISP? If you google "what is my ip", does it match the single IP you're talking about? If so, then you would need to negotiate with your ISP for additional external IPs.

Worth Noting that @JamesJJ is correct. Using additional IPs to 'trick' the API into allowing more connections is most likely a violation of that site's TOS and may result in your access getting terminated.